# How do I get rid of the seams after merging these two objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I merged two objects and each object had teeth that fit in with each other. However, after merging them the teeth are still visible and if you rotate the object you can see light between the teeth (indicating they don't fit perfectly). How do I get a perfect fit and remove the seam?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to remove them manually, but could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: added the file to it

Comment: I later saw this and found https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/bool_tools.html to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there won't be any magical trick, you can use a series of tricks like for example select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* (with a *Merge Distance* of 0.0005 m), deselect all and top bar > *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces* and delete the faces, select all again and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*:

[image]

Also remove these edges, dissolve some useless vertices, remove some floating edges, etc:

[image]

Select these edge loops and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Then <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*:

[image]

When you have finished one side, symmetrize, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting all items you want to merge and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. Or you can right click and select join.

I later ran into issues with this in the same way. Using Bool Tool seems to work as expected without fixing the merged object. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/bool_tools.html

Comment: That is how I joined it. But it leaves the seam.